# Best material for Piezometer tube in water well

Tags: hydrology, groundwater, underground-water

I have a 150M deep borehole. We want to measure ground water level using a pressure sensor.

I believe that it is best practice to make use of a `Piezometer tube` before installing the actual sensor.

- This prevents the sensor from getting tangled with the pump
- Large pumps can create a vortex current which will cause the sensor to move round
- Also helps smooth out any irregularities in the water level.

I was wandering what is the best type of piping to use for this tube?

I am biased towards using a pvc pipe as it does not have any radial bend and can therefore be inserted into the well much easier. However I would have to join many smaller segments together and I am concerned that these joins might come undone over time. Vertically hanging 150m of 30mm pvc will probably be quite heavy.

Comment: And why not to fix the pressure sensor and cable to the pump pipe?

Comment: What is the well diameter and the diameter of the pump riser?What is the water level vs the pump level? It might be possible to set the transducer far enough above the pump so it won't be a problem. You can get threaded pvc so you don't have to rely on glue.

Comment: @CamiloRada we can certainly do that. We would just have pull the pump up in order to do that.

Comment: @Zapnologica Well that sounds like a cost effective option. Also, unless the well goes dry sometimes perhaps the sensor can be several meters or tens of meters above the pump. In such case maybe the tube is not necessary at all.